# Design question: Should the client both create the session and the socket?

Tags: language-agnostic, law-of-demeter

I have three classes:

- **Client**
- **Session**
- **Socket**

Both Session & Socket depeand on the Client to create both objects.
A Session depeands on a Socket and no sockets are created without a session.
Should the Client have a function that creates a Session pubically and a Socket privately?
Doesn't it violate the law of demeter?
EDIT:
Current code:

```
class Client
{
private:
  // Connection details
public:
  shared_ptr<Socket> createSocket(); // returns a new socket if the connection is opened
}

class Session
{
public:
  Session(Client &); // Accepts a client and gets a socket for i/o to the server
}
```

Now something tells me that the session shouldn't be responsible for getting the socket from the client and that the client should create the session.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. All you are telling us about `Client` is that it creates both `Session` and `Socket`, nothing more.

If `Client` needs to use both, then there is no violation. If it only creates `Socket` in order to provide it to `Session`, I would say this *is* a violation and `Session` should get `Socket` itself.

Comment: Client contains internal objects which connect to the server.
After a connection is made, currently I have a function that returns a new socket. The session object accepts a client and in the ctor it calls the function that creates the new socket for this session.
Should that be changed? If so, how?

Comment: Again, if `Client` does not use the socket, the socket creation should probably be moved to the `Session`.

Comment: But all the data required to create a socket is on the client since the internals that connect to the server are also used to create a socket (this is a given from my networking library). I can't dismiss the client class since it tracks the sessions.

Comment: @the_drow - Perhaps you need to extract the shared information into a class of its own?

Comment: @Oded: Code added. Please review the question.

Comment: @the_drow - I would say the connection details deserve a class of their own. Create them in the `Client` and only pass that through to the `Session`.

Comment: @Oded: That way I can handle a connection pool using connection objects. Thanks.